# How can I calculate the date specified by a rule like "The second Monday in May" for a gievn year using PHP?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, php

I need to store a list of holidays in a MySQL database table, and be able to generate and output the exact date these holidays will fall on in any given year using PHP.

For some this is easy (they fall on a given date every year), but for many others the holiday falls on the [first/second/third etc] [day of week] in [month]. What would be the most efficient way to store these date rules in a MySQL table, then calculate and output the exact date the holiday will fall on for any given year, using MySQL and PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
$time = strtotime('second monday of may 2012');
echo date('Y-m-d, H:i:s', $time);
```

Output:

```
2012-05-14, 00:00:00
```

Comment: I had no idea PHP even had this functionality - that's amazing. Thanks so much!

Comment: But be careful, string has to be *properly* formatted. E.g., `second monday of may 2012` will be translated as `2nd monday of may, year 2012`, while `second monday of may, 2012` (with comma between month and year) will be translated as `second monday of may, current year, time 20:12:00`. Many strings won't be decoded at all.

Answer (score 1):

you could try [strtotime()](http://php.net/function.strtotime)